# How to search for special characters in my database with an sql query in an accent insensitive way?

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I have a table in my db that contains several columns and in some of them there are special characters like á, é, í, ó, ú, Á, É, Í, Ó, Ú, ñ and Ñ. I have in my webpage a search box and by using this I make a query that searches my bd table and displays the results like this:

Searching form:

```
<form action="resultado.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    <th scope="col"><label for="busqueda"></label>
    <input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar" width="auto" placeholder="Buscar..." height="auto" />
  </th>
  <th scope="col" align="center" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="ACTION" class="button1" value="Buscar"></th>
</tr></form>
```

Button function:

```
 if (@$_POST['ACTION']=='Buscar'){ 
 $buscar = $_POST['buscar'];
 $query = "SELECT * FROM Medios_table WHERE concat(id,UPPER(Id_Nombre),UPPER(Pais),UPPER(Estado),UPPER(Ciudad),UPPER(website),UPPER(Url),UPPER(Url2),UPPER(InfAnex) COLLATE uft8_unicode_ci) LIKE UPPER('%$buscar%') ORDER BY Id_Nombre ASC";
 $busquedaresult = mysql_query($query);}
```

In my table I have several columns that contains words like `"Andalucía"` and `"España"` many times as a result from this query if I type in the search box `"andalucia"` nothing comes up, but if I type `"Andalucía"` now it does show up, if I search `"Espana"` nothing shows up but `"España"` works fine, I cannot make it accent insensitive. my table and column collation is `utf8_unicode_ci` and my webpage meta looks like this:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I'm using a phpMyAdmin in my website to create or modify my db and it has the MySQL server 5.1.1